# Change css background image depending on site

Tags: css, image, background

Is it possible for css to change background image depending on which site we are?
For example, when I am on a index.php, I want to see images/index.png, and when I am on first.php I want to have /images/image.png.

Comment: you can do that using javascript or load different `.css` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background by leaving it blank on css.

```
<style>
body
{
background-image: url(/images/index.png);
}
</style>
```

And use that on every webpage.

Comment: Thank you very much, works as intended :) I don't know why I couldn't think about this easy solution.